# Query Builder Laravel Left Join

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I'm using laravel 8, and I make a query builder to make a left join, when laravel execute the query show me a error, but in SQL Server MS execute correctly

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Invalid column name '2'. (SQL: select [a].[id] as [id1],
> [b].[id] as [id2], [a].[reg], [a].[parte], [a].[ubiclinea],
> [a].[descripcion], [a].[numConteo] as [conteo1], [a].[cantidad] as
> [cantidad1], [a].[counter] as [contador1], [a].[created_at] as
> [created1], [b].[numConteo] as [conteo2], [b].[cantidad] as
> [cantidad2], [b].[counter] as [contador2], [b].[created_at] as
> [created2] from [directosCount] as [a] left join [directosCount] as
> [b] on [a].[reg] = [b].[reg] and [b].[numConteo] = [2] and
> [b].[deleted_at] is null where [a].[numConteo] = 1 and
> [a].[deleted_at] is null)

that is the error that show

but I copy the query and execute in SQL Server and it works

my query in laravel is this

```
DB::table('directosCount as a')
->leftJoin('directosCount as b', function($join)
{
    $join->on('a.reg', '=', 'b.reg');
    $join->on('b.numConteo', '=', '2')->whereNull('b.deleted_at');
})
->select('a.id as id1', 'b.id as id2', 'a.reg', 'a.parte', 'a.ubiclinea', 'a.descripcion', 'a.numConteo as conteo1', 'a.cantidad as cantidad1', 'a.counter as contador1', 'a.created_at as created1', 'b.numConteo as conteo2', 'b.cantidad as cantidad2', 'b.counter as contador2', 'b.created_at as created2')
->where('a.numConteo', '1')
->whereNull('a.deleted_at')
->get();
```

hope someone can help me

Comment: the `join->on` is comparing columns not a column to a value, that would need a `where` to compare the value I would assume

Comment: @gutiec - Good to know you solved the problem, post an answer to your own question so it does not show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

i think this should be outside of join

```
$join->on('b.numConteo', '=', '2')->whereNull('b.deleted_at');
```

please change `on` to `where`

```
->where('b.numConteo', '=', '2')->whereNull('b.deleted_at');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `on` statements in your join. Try this

```
DB::table('directosCount as a')
->leftJoin('directosCount as b', function($join)
{
    $join->on('a.reg', '=', 'b.reg')
       ->where('b.numConteo', '=', '2')
       ->whereNull('b.deleted_at');
})
->select('a.id as id1', 'b.id as id2', 'a.reg', 'a.parte', 'a.ubiclinea', 'a.descripcion', 'a.numConteo as conteo1', 'a.cantidad as cantidad1', 'a.counter as contador1', 'a.created_at as created1', 'b.numConteo as conteo2', 'b.cantidad as cantidad2', 'b.counter as contador2', 'b.created_at as created2')
->where('a.numConteo', '1')
->whereNull('a.deleted_at')
->get();
```